# Eligibility for being a protected question

Tags: discussion

What is the criteria that a question needs to satisfy in order to have it protected by a moderator? It seems to me that this protection is some sort of honor to a question.

Comment: Note also that members with >15k rep can also protect a question after 1 or 2 days.

Comment: It's not really an honour. It's an administrative necessity and it should be temporary wherever possible.

Answer (score 10):

A moderator needs to decide that it is attracting (or will attract) too many low quality answers from people not part of our site culture.

That's it.

Any post that ends up on the Hot Network Questions is likely to need protection.

---

It is not an honor, but a means of protecting the site from  sudden and unfocused inflows of people who have no interest in participating in the site's culture.

In my opinion many questions which need protection are not particularly good questions for the stated mission of the site, but are instead very accessible questions.

Comment: I am just little bit confused as to what you are actually meaning by by _low-quality answer._ Check [my question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210777/); it got three answers all of which are quite good & received positive votes from the community; still the question was _protected_. Why? Are those three answers of low-quality?? Do those people _have no interest in participating in the site's culture_? I don't think so; could you please clarify that?

Comment: You'd have to ask Qmechanic why he protected it. I have no idea. In any case, two of the answers you got are from regulars and their ability to answer is not affected by protection.

Comment: You meant to say the third one is wrong answer? And that's why Qmechanic _protected_ the question? Is it so?

Comment: I've have no opinion about the answers to your question. I didn't protect it and don't know why Qmechanic thought it was necessary to do so. Presumptive he did so on a preventative basis, but *you would have to ask him to be sure*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply:)

Comment: @user36790 : Note that dmckee's answer leaves the possibility of  protection against _future_ low quality answers (LQAs), so protection doesn't necessarily imply current LQAs. Also note that there could be deleted LQAs only visible to 10k+ users. Generally speaking, I usually don't protect question with less than 3 answers. Concerning [your above mentioned question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210777/2451), it received 3 answers within 4 minutes, which indicates a potential for many answers. Therefore I protected it. I can un-protect it, if you think it would be better.

Comment: @Qmechanic: It simply depends upon you, sir. If you think it is better to _protect_, then protect it. You run the disciplinary of this site, so if by _protecting_, it adds to that cause, then I've no problem. You know much better than me what to do. I only wanted to know why mine was protected in the context of dmckee's answer; that's it. I've no offence to you:)

Comment: One should add that ideally protection should have a limited timespan, particularly with questions in the HNQ sidebar which can normally be unprotected relatively soon after they leave the sidebar. Questions like [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61073) should remain protected, but if you find an old (>1 month) question that's protected with no obvious reason, it is reasonable to flag it for moderator attention with a message along the lines of "unprotect?".